# why is my discord.py command not working or sending messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have this edit snipe command and event in which if a user edits a messages it snipes it. The event works fine and sends the edited messages into a private logs admin channel. However, when I try to make this into a command and it send an embed into the given command channel the message and command does not work at all

```
    @commands.command()
    async def es(self,message_before, message_after):
        embed=discord.Embed(description=f"**Message sent by** {author} **edited in** {channel}")
        embed.set_author(name= f" ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ {message_before.author.name}#{message_before.author.discriminator}")
        embed.add_field(name="Old message", value=message_before.content, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="New message", value=message_after.content, inline=False)
        await message_before.channel.send(embed=embed)
        return
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing **command** and **event**.

In the previous answer by [@Cohen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14540754/cohen) in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746718/discord-py-bot-edit-snipe-command-that-snipes-the-recently-edited-message), he told you to use the `on_message_edit` event. This event ([and many others](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-api-events)) are already defined by the discord.py library, hence they already provide the input parameters.

If you want to send an embed **each** time an user edits a message, do not do it in a separate function, add your code to the piece of code in `on_message_edit`. If, on another hand, you want to be able to call a command ("*!es*") for example, who will retrieve the **last** edited message, you will need to create a database and keep a log of the edited messages (a single table with a *old_message* and *new_message* columns).

You can use [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to create and manually check your database, and I suggest using an asynchronous library such as [**aiosqlite**](https://readthedocs.org/projects/aiosqlite/) which works well with **discord.py**